# Copper fills in top and bottom layer from a cost perspective

Tags: pcb, ground-plane, copper-pour, cost

I've seen low-cost boards from consumer electronics that have just tracks connecting the pins and they will have no copper ground pours. Since making these as cheap as possible is the goal, doesn't it make sense to have a copper pour because there will be less copper to etch away which means less time to manufacture which in turn (I hope) reduces the cost?

How would one go about designing a small 2-layer board that has no critical functions when the only priority is to be as cheap as possible?

Comment: If the board has vias, the outer layers use an additive process for copper deposition. Copper is often reclaimed from the etchant.

Comment: I doubt that the copper fill in a 2 layer board will have any impact on price up to astronomical quantities of boards. The etching time depends on copper thickness and on the thinnest feature size, but not on the total copper fill ratio.

Answer (score 2):

The PCB production process requires PCB etchant to remove unwanted areas of copper on the board. The more copper left in the board, then less copper etchant need to be used. Ground planes takes a lot of area of PCB and it can save more etchant, so the process is cheaper. I don't think that lack of ground planes makes PCB more cheap.

Comment: You use more etchant, but you don't need more time. So I am not sure that taking off more copper is more expensive.. That etched copper is a ressource in itself. Highly pure copper that can be directly used in many processes.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about it. You need to be purchasing PCBs in the *millions* before questions of copper amount, core material (usually punched phenolic-paper or phenolic-glass) and others come in.

Even multilayer FR-4 can get to fractions of a USD per board, in quantities of thousands.  Parts and assembly dominate product cost.

Comment: So why do you think they opt for such boards with no ground planes? Can it be because they might be using machines that are very old? Any board from vintage electronics will have just the tracks. That's where I'm coming to this thought.

Comment: Well, going back to the vintage days, layers used to cost more, and designs were often hand drawn -- planes/pours are a right pain to do by hand. Automated design tools and ever more refined fabrication processes have reduced costs of higher-quality materials (FR-4 over phenolic) and especially prototypes (which now cost dollars instead of tens or hundreds each). And they had other motivations for EMC, such as slower signals, and shields or chassis.